# Regular expression for non-standard csv file

Tags: regex, csv

I am trying to figure out the solution for correct parsing of non-standard csv file. Csv delimiter is comma. The problem is, I have to parse 6th field, but there can be zero to many commas inside it.
For better visualization is this field enclosed in quotes and for example is there one comma. Quotes there may not be.
So I need to parse everything after 5th field and before three fields from the end.

### Examples:

Record no.1:

```
546511,56756121,None,None,channel10,"abcd,efgh",2016-11-29 22:50:00+01:00,125.0,False
```

Regex result: "abcd,efgh"

---

Record no.2:

```
546511,56756121,None,None,channel10,ij,kl,mnop,2016-11-29 22:50:00+01:00,125.0,False
```

Regex result: ij,kl,mnop

---

Record no.3:

```
546511,56756121,None,None,channel10,stuvwxyz,2016-11-29 22:50:00+01:00,125.0,False
```

Regex result: stuvwxyz

---

What is the correct regular expression for this please?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Not the best. But would do the job. `(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(\d.*?),(.*?),(.*)` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hVPqRR/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
^(?:[^,\n]+,){5}(.*)(?:,[^,\n]*){3}$
```

It matches the first five fields (any non `,` character, one or more times, followed by a `,`. Then it **captures** the desired data. Finally it matches the final three fields.

Result in capture group 1.

(If you need to just match, you have to specify regex flavor.)

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HhHUbo/1).

**Edit**

OK, after considering your comment, try this:

```
^([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),(.*),([^,]+)\+\d\d:\d\d,([^,]+),([^,\n]+)$
```

[Here at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HhHUbo/2).

(NB! If you only intend to match one instance, you don't need a quantifier `{1}`.)

**Edit 2**

OK. Here we go again.

It's not possible to remove the quotes inside the group with one operation. You can however remove surrounding quotes with

```
^([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),"?(.*?)"?,([^,]+)\+\d\d:\d\d,([^,]+),([^,\n]+)$
```

[Here at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HhHUbo/3). (Slightly modified to better visualize.)

Comment: Thanks! I have modified your regex to this one:
`^([^,]+){1},([^,]+){1},([^,]+){1},([^,]+){1},([^,]+){1},(.*),([^,]+){1},([^,]+){1},([^,]+){1}$`
because I have realized, I need to group each field separately for next processing.
Is it possible modify this regex to ignore "+01:00" in timestamp? Thanks

Comment: Thanks again! It's working perfect. And the last thing which I realized is to ignore all quotes inside 6th field. 
Examples:
If there will be `"abcd,efgh"`, it returns `abcd,efgh`
If there will be `"ab"cd,e""fgh"`, it returns `abcd,efgh`

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark as accepted answer and maybe up-vote ;) (that's how people with similar questions finds help)

Comment: can you help me with my issue which I have described in my last comment please? :) If it is possible ...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can specify the bounds around the phrase that you want to extract.  For example (assuming that one one side there is a test like 'channelxx' and there is a date on the other side).  Like so.

```
^.\*channel[0-9][0-9],(.\*),20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] .*
```